# How to get a single object from a list of Objects in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have List of User object, I just want to get a Collect object from List based on variables in User object.

```
public class User {

    private int id;

    private String sex;

    private int year;

   private int value;

    /**
     * Getter and setter for all variables
     */
}
```

I have a model class like this. Now I have a list of User objects.

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
```

I want to create a single object which contains the sum of all the  values fro monthly salary

```
List<Collect> objList = new ArrayList<Collect>();
for(User object : users) {
    if(object.getyear().equals("2013")){
        ageList.add(object);
    }
}
```

but I am not sure how it will work. As there might be multiple entries in for the same year and I want to sum all the values for the same year and put into the collect object

is there any way where I can create a single object from the list of object and also perform a sum operation based on the same year from the list of object. Also, don't want to hardcode 2013 for checking year.

Comment: So, for example, you want to sum `value` of all `user` whose `year` is 2013?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I think you want a reduction operation, but it could be a grouping one? You talk about your User object, but it doesn't have a monthly salary. You talk about a Collect object, but we see nothing of it.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn yes

Comment: @ifly6 I want to sum all the values for the same years ..for example 2013, 2014 2016 etc. but without hardcoding the year

Comment: "single object" is too vague. Can you clarify what do you mean by that?

Comment: Ya so you want to get total value per year right? check my answer

Comment: @BheshGurung  if I have a list of object and then I want to create a single object from it. this single object contains only sum and year for example total_sum for year 2013 = xxxxx etc

Comment: In that case, a `Map` is sufficient, and you already have two answers that provide what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imperative way to do this, not the streamified way, would be to use a for-loop similar to the way you're already doing it.

What you can do, however, to get the list of all years for which you want, so you don't need to hard code it, is two-fold. First, I would create a Map for years and salary sums (if not loosely typed `Map<Year, Salary>` although this would probably take the form `Map<Integer, Integer>`).

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, I would run through the list of users initialising the values for the `HashMap` and adding the values to the initialised values in the `HashMap` in a single loop.

```
for (User u : users)
    if (map.containsKey(u.getYear()))
        map.put(u.getYear(), map.get(u.getYear()) + u.getSalary());
    else map.put(u.getYear(), 0);
```

The map would then contain the sums you want by year. And you would get them by querying `map.get(year)`.

Comment: I can do it with stream :-?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I wonder if your solution can be as flexible as this one. For example, if you suspect that the sum could be too large for an integer.

Comment: If the result is too large for int, just use `sumToLong`

Comment: Here, you would have to make two changes. First, you would use `Map<Integer, BigInteger>` and change it from `map.get(u.getYear()) + ...` to `map.get(u.getYear()).add(new BigInteger(u.getSalary()))`, assuming that the salary is still an integer.

Comment: summingLong. In your code you need that change to. :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to sum for every year right, here's the way:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> totalValuePerYear = users.stream()
                       .collect(groupingBy(User::getYear, summingInt(User::getValue)));
```

If you want to collect it to a object, such as:

```
public class SumPerYear {
    private int year;
    private int sum;
    // Getter, setter, constructor
}
```

You can do one step further:

```
List<SumPerYear> result = users.stream()
                       .collect(groupingBy(User::getYear, summingInt(User::getValue)))
                       .entrySet().stream()
                       .map(e -> new SumPerYear(e.getKey, e.getValue))
                       .collect(toList());
```

Comment: +1. With the same level of flexibility, IMO, this is more concise and preferable than the imperative version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IntStream` for that:

```
long totalSum =  users.stream()
    .filter(user -> user.getYear() == 2013))
    .mapToInt(User::getValue)
    .sum();
```

Of course you can declare the year in a variable, parameter, read it from commandline, ... to not have it hardcoded.